# Flask session not preserved on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, python, ios, flask, session

I'm new to Flask and I decided that the best way to learn it is to jump straight in the deep end and try to make an app from scratch. I have successfully made it and it works perfectly on desktop, but sessions aren't maintained when I try to use my mobile. I have an iPhone 12 and I've tried it on Chrome, Safari, Opera and Firefox and none work. It works on Edge, Chrome and Firefox (those were all I tested on) on my desktop PC.

Here is my init file:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, make_response, render_template, session, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "Actual one is a fixed, random string like 89hsfd98sdhf89u983qwj9"

@app.route('/')
def index(): return render_template('index.html')

# This is where the session is created
@app.route('/player/add', methods=['POST'])
def player_add():
     req = request.get_json()
     session['session_key'] = _generate_session_key(STRING_LENGTH)
     session['name'] = req['name']
     return make_response(jsonify({"result": player.player_add(req['name'], session['session_key'])}), 200)


# This is the important one where the session is called
@app.route('/player', methods=['GET'])
def get_session_name():
     try:
          if not _valid_session(): return make_response(jsonify({'status': False}), 200)
          data = player.player_info(session['name'])
     except: data = {'status': False}
     return make_response(jsonify(data), 200)
"""
Many more app routes
"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()`
```

If it helps, I communicate with the Flask server from the frontend using fetch like this:

```
fetch(`${window.origin}/player`, {
    method: "GET",
    credentials: "include",
    cache: "no-cache",
    headers: new Headers({
        "content-type": "application/json"
    })
}).then(...)
```

If a session has been made, then the app will display the user's entered name. If not, it will prompt the user to enter their name (and start a session). Again, it works perfectly on desktop browsers, but with mobile it just responding as if no session has been created (which is {'status': False}).

There's probably a lot of bad practice here, but I've been researching for a while and I have no idea why it would only work on desktop and not mobile. Please let me know if I should provide more information.

The site is being hosted on PythonAnywhere, if that helps. No errors on the console or from the backend.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated! Even if the problem persists, at least being able to use it on mobile with a few temporary settings changes would be alright.

I've tried:

- Using `credentials: "same-origin"` when calling `fetch`
- Setting:

  - `app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem`
  - `app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False`
  - `app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE'] = True`
  - `app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE'] = 'None'`
- Using HTTPS instead of HTTP
- Disabled 'Prevent Cross-Site Tracking' (essentially allowing for third-party cookies)
- Clearing the sessions and regenerating the `SECRET_KEY`
- Clearing all stored cookies and history in the browser

Comment: app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE'] = 'Strict'. ( there is no point in using None when using flask unless you host your client side on a different server. app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE'] = True  ( this is correct but some browsers reject it at debug) unless you implement https for your debug environment set it to False. Do not forget to revert to True when in production